# Getting URL parameters using $route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following url:

```
http://myurl.dev/users/32
```

I want to pass the last parameter `32` to a `$http.get request` but I can't figure out how to pass it.

So far I have this:

```
var matchmaker = angular.module('matchmaker', ['ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
})
.controller('LocationCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', '$route', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, $route) {

    var id = $route.current.params.id;

    console.log(id);

    $http.get('http://myurl.dev/services/' + id ).success(function(data) 
    {
        $scope.applicants = data;
    });

}]);
```

In the console it's saying:

> Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

**Edit:**

Angular isn't generating the url, it's a server side generated url

**Edit 2.0**

Here's the config for the routeProvider with actual route parameters:

```
var matchmaker = angular.module('matchmaker', ['ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
})
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/matchmaker/locations/:id', {
    controller: 'LocationCtrl'
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: You can use `$routeParams.id` for this.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655877/angularjs-get-current-url-parameters

Comment: you have a huge gap between the $ and routeParams

Answer (score 0):

Put a `console.log($routeParams);` in your controller and check its value.

If it is `Object {}` check if you have a route definition using parameters:

```
var module = angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute']);

module.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/test/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    controller: 'TestController'
  });

  // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

If so, you will get this output in the console:

```
Object {id: "42"}
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get Object{} in the console. I should have said (although not sure if this matters) that Angular isn't generating the url, it's a server side generated url. Does that make a difference? As you can tell I'm a total Angular noob!

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Maybe add your routing definitions to the question.

Comment: I've updated my original post with (what I think you mean by) my routing definitions

Comment: I don't see an obvious error. You could create a Plunker which demonstrates it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you trying to get value which doesn't exist at that moment, that's how javascript works. You need to specify that you want these values when they are ready using '[$routeChangeSuccess](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route#%24routeChangeStart)' event.

```
.controller('PagesCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $route) {
    //If you want to use URL attributes before the website is loaded
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        //You can use your url params here
        $http.get('http://myurl.dev/services/' + $routeParams.id )
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.applicants = data;
        });
    });
});
```