# MVC AngularJs Handling query string

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have CourseAPi Controller that containing follwing method :

```
 public IEnumerable<CoursesDTO> Get(int id)
    {
        var x = _uniManager.GetCourses(id);
        return x;
    }
```

i want to send id from URl to this method using Angualr js 
the AngularJs  controller :

```
app.controller('CRUD_OperController', function ($scope, $filter, CRUD_OperService, $location) {



GetAllRecords1();
function GetAllRecords1() {
    var id = 12;
    var promiseGetSingle = CRUD_OperService.get(id);
    promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl)
    { $scope.Courses = pl.data },
          function (errorPl) {
             // $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
          });
}
```

});

My angular service :

```
app.service('CRUD_OperService', function ($http) {



//Get All Student  
this.getAllStudent = function () {

    return $http.get("/api/CourseApi/" );
}

//Get Single Records

this.get = function (id) {
    return $http.get("/api/CourseApi/" + id);
}
```

});

my webapi config

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();



        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi1",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

        );

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
```

Update : it return me error
 GET http://localhost:54070/api/CourseApi/12 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: how to user angualr to get the id in URL (http://localhost:54070/Course/index/15) to sned to the api controller

Answer (score 0):

This is the format I have used for such a task:

```
   this.$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/courseapi/' + id
    }).then(function (pl) { 
        $scope.Courses = pl.data
    }, function (errorPl) {
          $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
    });
```

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: not working for me  return this  error : ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: What's the error? There are many other things that could cause an error. What's the name of your controller class? How is the routing set up?

Comment: check edit for web api confic and my api controller name (CourseApi)

Comment: The name of your controller class needs to end in Controller and be in the Controllers folder. `Controllers\CourseApiController.cs` with class name: `public class CourseApiController`. Also, I am updating the url in the example I gave to reflect your class name.

Comment: 1) Did you rename / relocate your webapi controller? 2) Does record with Id #12 exist?

Comment: my web api controller under controller folder and id=12 is for test becuase give my error undediend id

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two options:

The first one: configure routes in your angular controller using ng-route, inject $routeParams module and then retrieve the parameters using it. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655877/angularjs-get-current-url-parameters-using-ngroute) and the [Angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) for more info.

The second option is to get url location and manipulate string in order to get the parameter:

```
var tokens = $location.absUrl().split("/");
var id = tokens[5]
```

I prefer the first option, it's "cleaner" than the second. Hope it can help you!

Comment: thank you the second solution working fine but i still have error

Comment: error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)