# How to get the query parameter from the requested URL in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to take the last value in this url: 
http://localhost:60954/Home/Index/**3**

I made this angular app but the object is always undefined

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    console.log("in ctrlr");
    console.log("parameter");
    console.log($routeParams);
//this always doesn't work. Should I define `id` somewhere?

    console.log($routeParams.id);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS get current URL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655877/angularjs-get-current-url-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You're already injecting `$routeParams` into your controller. You just have to use it as well.

```
$routeParams.queryParam
```

Answer (score 0):

`$routeProvider.when('/index/**:id'**, {
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        });`

Where are :**id** is the param name.So, You should call the param name with the $routeParams like as $routeParams.id

Comment: Is it one asterisk or two or four or zero, what is it all about??

Comment: did you configure your url parameter name in $routeprovider?

Comment: Yes: `app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Index/:id*', { controller: 'clinicController'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});`

Comment: See the controller name is different `'clinicController'`. You can get the `id` param value from `'clinicController'` only. You can't it from  `'myController'`

Comment: They are the same actually, I used more generic name in the question

Comment: Then the problem may be for that.

Comment: No, there is no `myController` only `clinicController`

Comment: see the above comment which you wrote here. there have a controller name `{ controller: 'clinicController'}); `

Answer (score 0):

I was missing adding `ng-view` attribute to the container element.